# Why stat(2) on location /proc/<pid>/<files> always give a empty size

Tags: c, linux

It seems that I can't cast `stat(2)` or `fstat(2)` on the (pseudo-)file under /proc to get it size.

```
file: test.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    struct stat st;
    stat(argv[1],&st);
    printf("%d\n",st.st_size);  
}
```

compile it with `cc test.c`

```
$./a.out /etc/passwd
2495
$./a.out /proc/self/environ
0
$./a.out /proc/self/maps
0
$ stat /proc/self/environ
<some output> 
Size: 0             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   regular empty file
<some output>
$ file /proc/self/cmdline 
/proc/self/cmdline: empty
```

`read(2)` and `fread(3)` could get the content successfully.
However, `lseek(2)`, `lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END)` takes no effect;

My questions:

1 Is it a intention? 
2 Is there an easy way similar to `stat(2)` to tell the content size in this case other than read all the content and count the bytes by ourselves.

Comment: Good overview on why these files would read as 0 bytes: https://superuser.com/a/619961/694192

Comment: This seems intentional, since these files are not physically stored on disk … `stat(1)` also fails, and reports empty files. Why do you need this? Just read the objects directly.

Comment: I'm trying to peek the environment variables of a running process via /proc/<pid>/environ, as it's '\0' terminated strings, i would like to pretty print in '\n'. in this case i found `stat(2)` always output it's 0 sized, lol. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @Source This would give you the wrong information even if it worked. The process of reading the file is transformational here, looking up information in real-time. No matter what number you get for the size of the file, there's no guarantee it would equal the number of bytes you'd read because these aren't plain, binary files.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Your statement stays true,  however,  at least we could grab a snapshot at that very moment.

Comment: @Source There is nothing to take a snapshot of. The reading of the file creates the output. It's like reading a binary file in text mode. Even if there was a size of the file that you could get, there would be no reason to expect it to equal the number of bytes that you would read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that you'll have to read the file to know the size of the contents since it is a special file, as covered here in depth: https://superuser.com/questions/619955/how-does-proc-work/

> When a program wants to read from a file, it will issue various system
>   library calls which ultimately end up in the kernel in the form of an
>   open(), read(), close() sequence (possibly with seek() thrown in for
>   good measure). The kernel takes the provided path and filename, and
>   through the file system and device I/O layer translates these to
>   physical read requests (and in many cases also write requests -- think
>   for example atime updates) to some underlying storage.
>
> However, it doesn't have to translate those requests specifically to
>   physical, persistent storage. The kernel's contract is that issuing
>   that particular set of system calls will provide the contents of the
>   file in question. Where exactly in our physical realm the "file"
>   exists is secondary to this.